# Python xml.etree.ElementTree: ATTLIST override default value in get() method

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree, dtd

I have this test XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE main [
<!ELEMENT main (object+)>
    <!ELEMENT object (description, year, manufacturer)>
        <!ATTLIST object name CDATA #REQUIRED>
        <!ATTLIST object works (yes|no) "yes">
        <!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT manufacturer (#PCDATA)>
]>

<main>
    <object name="My object">
        <description>This is a simple object</description>
        <year>2022</year>
        <manufacturer>Myself</manufacturer>
    </object>
</main>
```

and this piece of Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree


try:
    xml_data = xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse("test.xml", events=("start", "end"))

    for event, xml_tag in xml_data:
        if event == "end" and xml_tag.tag == "object":
            object_name = xml_tag.get("name")
            object_description = xml_tag.find("description").text
            works = xml_tag.get("works")

            print("works value: " + str(works))

            xml_tag.clear()

    print("Done!")

except (NameError, xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError):
    print("XML error!")
```

The output of the code is this:

```
works value: yes
Done!
```

Reading library documentation I can't find any tip on ATTLIST value, **works** attribute is not present for object element so I expect that the code return this output:

```
works value: None
Done!
```

If I remove this line from XML

```
<!ATTLIST object works (yes|no) "yes">
```

the output is what I expect. I tried to use

```
works = xml_tag.get("works", default=None)
```

without success. Is there a way to override ATTLIST default value? XML is out of my control and it can change over time

Comment: I can reproduce this. ElementTree does not validate XML documents, but it processes `ATTLIST` declarations that occur in the internal subset and sets default values. I think this is standard behaviour of the Expat parsing library, which is used under the hood. The ElementTree documentation is silent about it.

Comment: It is a bug in get() method. Documentation says that when attribute is not found the return value is _default_: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a bug in the `get()` method. The attribute **is** indeed found. It is not present in the XML instance, but it is defined with a default value in the internal `DOCTYPE` declaration.

Comment: Reported issue here: https://bugs.python.org/issue46798

Comment: OK but as I said, I'm not convinced that it is a bug. It could be "surprising" behaviour that is in at least some sense correct but insufficiently documented.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right but in this way we'll known which was the developers idea. In the end the documentation must be updated

Comment: I received a very stupid answer on the issue that said a change breaks old code... Current implementation: `def get(self, key, default=None)`. Proposed implementation: `def get(self, key, default=None, double_value=False)`. When _double_value_ is **True** return both `get()` and document default values. In which way this could break existing code?!?!?! Now this is out of control, developer can control the code, not the XML written by others. And it's impossible to know if the attribute really exists